# Can you have a .NET MAUI Shell Menu with ONLY MenuItems?

Tags: maui

We are trying to implement a shell menu without any navigation items and only menuitems.
this looks like in appshell.xaml.cs:

```
        Items.Add(new MenuItem
        {
            Text = "About Item",
            Command = new Command(menu_select),
            CommandParameter = "Menu About"
        });
```

When we try this we are getting an error:

"Active shell Item not set! Have you added any shell items to your shell?"

Should we assume that we must have a shellcontent item?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you must. Shell is similar to a page of tabs; some tab is always active. If you don’t want that, you don’t have to use Shell. Find line `MainPage = new AppShell();`, and change it to display a custom page that does whatever you want.